# Spring Batch Job how to rollback all steps in whole job?

Tags: java, spring

I need to implement a job which contains 3 steps. First step gets data from web service. Second step calls another web service to get additional data. And third step downloads images based on the data that we got from the first step.

Now, what happens internally there isnt so important. But one of the requirements is that if one of the steps fails, then all the previous work has to be cleaned up as well. For example, if something fails on the second step, then all data obtained from the first step, must be cleared as well. Because there cannot be inconsistent data.

Now I know that it is not in Spring Batch Job nature to do that, but is there still a way to achieve that? Maybe use some JobExecutionListener or something?

Or do I have to put all those steps into one step?

Comment: What are you doing with the data? How large is your dataset? Is it going into a database, or to a file, or to memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. In Spring Batch the transactionality is at the Chunk Level, so if you need to do some rollbacking that depends on your logic, you can do so by writing some cleanup strategies in you JobExecutionListener or at the level of StepExecutionListener depending on your need.

Comment: Okay. This answer has given me some light on how to procceed

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough for me. As I understood, you can be able to use `@Transactional` for rollback purpose. if you are calling different methods, create a transaction methods for each service and call everything inside your spring job.